# How to convert NSData to NSArray (or NSObject)

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver

I did test this code, but it cause SIGABRT error.

```
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]
```

NSData is plist data with xml format. This code works fine.

```
[urlData writeToFile:[self docPath] atomically:YES];
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self docPath]];
```

How can I change NSData to NSArray without file conversion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This assumes you have populated `NSString *filepath` with the filepath of your saved data file.

```
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSData *dataFromFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileNameWithPath];
NSArray *arrayFromFile = nil;
if (dataFromFile) {
    arrayFromFile = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:dataFromFile
                                                       mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainers
                                                                 format:&format 
                                                       errorDescription:NULL];
}
```

Hope that helps...